# How can backup and then modify a file with sed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, sed

I need to overwrite some configs on many servers at once and I want to modify the origianl config file while creating a backup, can all that be done with sed, just for curiosity?

Someone was mentioning this pattern, but it doesn't work.

```
new_port="..."
sed -i .bak "s/port=2334/${new_port}/g"
```

Comment: As there is an answer already I will only suggest to look for "perl pie" - it should be equally good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sed -i .bak "s/port=2334/${new_port}/g"
```

is nearly what you’re looking for; the fix is to remove the space after `-i`:

```
sed -i.bak "s/port=2334/${new_port}/g"
```

If `new_port` only has the port number, you’ll also have to repeat `port=`:

```
sed -i.bak "s/port=2334/port=${new_port}/g"
```

All of this only works if you actually specify the names of the files to be processed, after the `sed` expression.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with awk

```
awk '{print $0}' file >file.backup && awk '{gsub(/port=2334/,"port=${new_port}",$0);print }' file >tmpfile && mv tmpfile file
```

Comment: Just because something can be done in AWK doesn’t mean it’s a good idea to do it... Your first invocation is a slow `cp`, why not use that?